# Ruling on folding your trousers during Salah to prevent Isbal

Tags: salat

I have done my research on the topic of Isbal (where the lower garments cover the ankles), and I would like to prevent this from happening by folding my trousers up to not cover my ankles. But here's the issue, I have read that folding your garments during Salah is totally prohibited, meanwhile if I do not fold them they will cover the ankles. What do I do in this situation? I do not have alternative garments that are not too short or too long.

Comment: A tailor can alter the length of the trousers by cutting and overlocking.

Comment: I will do this, but as I said I don't have alternative garments that are not too short or too long, meaning I will have to face this issue until the trailor finishes his work on the clothes I gave to him. It takes time to do that and there's a waiting list, so any other temporary solution is needed

Answer (score 0):

Al Salam Alaykum brother, well done on what you're currently doing! It is the right approach in order not to be included among those in the Isbal Hadith insha Allah.

However, it would be more appropriate if you would fold your trousers up at all times, not only during Salah, as the prohibition of Isbal is not exclusive to during prayer only.

Here's a [reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3tit8J_NUU)